# Communicating between React-native and ASP.Net core RestfulAPI

Tags: react-native

I am having an issue getting my react-native app to communicate with my restful api backend.

This is backend controller

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class AuditController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Audits()
    {
        var audit = new List<AuditRequest>
        {
           new AuditRequest
           {
               Date = "23/04/2019 16:49:37",
               User ="Fiona",
               Message="Logon"
           },
           new AuditRequest
           {
               Date = "23/04/2019 16:49:37",
               User ="Fiona",
               Message="Logon"
           },
           new AuditRequest
           {
               Date = "23/04/2019 16:49:37",
               User ="Fiona",
               Message="Logon"
           }
        };
        return Ok(audit);
    }
}
```

Startup file

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddCors(opt =>
        {
            opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy =>
            {
                policy.AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials();
                //.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
            });
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

and my react file.

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://localhost:44354/audit")
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log("error");
      });
    //auditsActions.fetchAudits();
  }, []);
```

I am able to test the end-point using Postman.

The error i get is Network Error

- node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:15:0 in
- node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:88:12 in dispatchXhrRequest
- ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals.

I am using expo and an emulator
[image]

Can someone tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: whats your server end point?

Comment: i have tried 172.16.30.237 and localhost:19002

Comment: your `axios.get` URL should be like `http://(your pc IP address):44354/audit`

Comment: i got my ip address and tried "https://172.16.30.237:44354/audit" still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used this application  - coveyor by keyoti.